# Does an instance method not create an object reference in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-methods, instance-methods

I'm working on an asp.net web application in c#.  I have a public class called GetUser.  In that class I have a method called GetCurrentUser.  The method is as follows:

```
    public MobileUser GetCurrentUser(MDMDataContext dc, string userCode)
    {
        using (dc)
        {
            dc.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
            var currentUser =
                from MobileUser in dc.MobileUsers
                where MobileUser.UserCode == usercode                     
                select MobileUser;

            MobileUser mu = new MobileUser();
            mu = currentUser.Single();

            return mu;
        }
    }
```

But when I try to use the GetCurrentUser instance method as follows:

```
using (MDMDataContext dc = new MDMDataContext())
        {
            GetUser.GetCurrentUser(dc, "ABCD");
        }
```

I get the following error, **"An object reference for the non-static field, method or property '**....GetUser.GetCurrentUser....'

But if I add the static keyword to the function, the error goes away.  Can somebody please demystify this concept for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is an instance method, which means you need an instance on which to run it:

```
using (MDMDataContext dc = new MDMDataContext())
{
        GetUser user = new GetUser();
        user.GetCurrentUser(dc, "ABCD");
}
```

The `static` keyword means that the method is *static*, and available for the type as a whole, not tied to a specific instance.  That's why you can call it using the class name (and must call it that way) when it's marked static.

Comment: To add to that - `static` methods can only access other `static` things within a class since they aren't tied to a specific instance.

Comment: I gave myself a migraine yesterday trying to figure this out.  I was creating an instance of the return type of the function, not the class that contained the function.  If I understand correctly now, you can't use an instance method without creating an instance of the class containing the method definition.